# Overriding method implementation injection without direct inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, dependency-injection, polymorphism

Do you guys know if it's possible injecting the implementation of a method of a class A that does not inherit anything into a class C that inherits from a class B that provides the virtual method that A "overrides".

Basically, something like:

```
struct Base
  {
    virtual void print()
      {
      std::cout << " Base" << std::endl;
      }
  };

template<class T>
struct Super : public Base,
    protected T
  {
  using T::print; // Do some magic here
  };

struct Derived
  {
  void print()
    {
    std::cout << " Derived" << std::endl;
    }
  };

struct Derived2 : public Base
  {
  void print()
    {
    std::cout << " Derived2" << std::endl;
    }
  };
```

A small test case would be:

```
  Super<Derived> s;
  Base* base = &s;
  std::cout << "Base with Super<Derived>: ";
  base->print();
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Super<Derived>: ";
  s.print();
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Base with Derived: ";
  Derived2 d;
  Base* baseForDerived = &d;
  baseForDerived->print();
```

that prints:

```
TBase with Super<Derived>:  Base

Super<Derived>:  Derived

TBase with Derived:  Derived2
```

Ideally the first should print Derived.

The goal is to do this without performance penalties compared to Derived2, so no virtual inheritance or other kinds of indirections.

PS: No CRTP allowed in the "T" class, like: `template<class C> struct Derived : C {};`

Comment: just edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this what you want?

```
struct Base {
    virtual void print() {
        std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class T>
struct Super : Base, T {
    virtual void print() /* final */ override {
        T::print();
    }
};

struct Derived {
    void print() {
        std::cout << "Derived";
    }
};

struct Derived2 : Base {
    virtual void print() override {
        std::cout << "Derived2";
    }
};
```

Comment: I guess this is it. I tested and it totally works, didn't thought about just doing it, very good. How about performance penalties compared to the standard derived case?

Comment: @svoltron, optimizer can do a lot of things for you, so it's really hard to tell based on this toy example. But I don't see why there should be additional penalties here.

Comment: that's true. We shall see after some tests but I do think you're right. Thanks again